# Merchant republic retinue

Tags: crusader-kings-2

If, as the doge, I create a retinue, who inherits that retinue when I die. Does the retinue stick with the title of the doge? Or does it transfer to the new patrician of my house?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be transferred to your heir. It will stay under your control even if you lose the doge election.

Comment: Worked out just like you said. Accepted.